# Word problem involving interest rate

Tags: calculus

Zero coupon bonds require you to invest a certain amount of money now to yield the face value of the bonds when they come due. Suppose a bond is issued for a face value of $5,000 when it comes due in three years time. If the annual interest rate is 1.5% and interest is compounded continuously, how much money would the buyer have to invest now at the time of the initial purchase?

I got $4779.98 however, I don't know if that is the correct answer. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Hey Brittney, since you are new to Math StackExchange, I thought I would suggest that if you show the work you did to obtain your answer, then people will both be more willing to assist you, have better responses, and be able to answer more rapidly. Also, solving $5000 = P e^{.015 \cdot 3}$ for $P$ does yield both your answer and the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I get a value that rounds to $4779.99$ from $5000/\exp(.045)$

Answer (score 0):

Note the formula for continuous compound interest:

$5000=P \cdot e^{0.015 \cdot 3}$ Solve for P.

Where $P$ is the initial investment and the rest are parts of your criteria.

If you need help solving for $P$, let me know and I will assist you further.